# How do I transfer the values of a variable from one component to another in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I would like to transfer the value of the `textColor` variable from the `VerificationIndicator` component to the switch from the `VerificationGrid` component.

As you can see, I tried to use Input and Output decorator.

However, it seems that the first value reached by `textColor` is taken and not updated with the following ones.

How could I solve the problem?

Here is the html:

```
<app-verification-grid
                  [verificationGroupData]="
                    returnVerificationGroupLoadCaseDataBasedOnLoadCaseId(
                      x.CarPassengersStatusLaw.LoadCaseId
                    )
                  "
                  [verificationCriterions]="filterVerificationBaseCriterions()"
                  [testId]="x.Id"
                  [textColor]="textColor">
</app-verification-grid>

 <verification-indicator-cell style="padding-top:3px"
    [data]="findTargetToDisplay(vv,vcv.Unit)"(textColorChange)="textColor = $event">
     </verification-indicator-cell>
```

And these are the 2 components:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-verification-grid',
  templateUrl: './verification.grid.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./verification.grid.component.scss']
})
export class VerificationGrid implements OnInit {

  @Input()
  verificationGroupData: VerificationCriterionGroupLoadCase;

  @Input()
  verificationCriterions: Array<VerificationCriterion> = [];

  @Input()
  testId:any;

  @Input()
  textColor: string = 'white';

  noTarget: string = ""

  constructor(private translate: TranslateService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  getValue(i:any, j:any) {

    if(this.verificationCriterions.length < 1) return "-";

    // checks whether there are criteria defined for a pair of 'Row' and 'Column'
    let verificationCriterionsThatMatch = this.verificationCriterions.filter(x =>
      (x.VerificationCriterionGroup2.ID === this.verificationGroupData.Rows[i].ID ||
        x.VerificationCriterionGroup2.ID === this.verificationGroupData.Columns[j].ID) &&
       (x.VerificationCriterionGroup1.ID === this.verificationGroupData.Rows[i].ID ||
       x.VerificationCriterionGroup1.ID === this.verificationGroupData.Columns[j].ID) 
       )

    if (isNullOrUndefined(verificationCriterionsThatMatch) ||
        verificationCriterionsThatMatch.length < 1)
    {
        return "-";
    }

    if (verificationCriterionsThatMatch.length > 1)
    {
        return "*";
    }

    //only one verification criteria is present
    let verificationCriterion = verificationCriterionsThatMatch[0];

    if (verificationCriterion.VerificationValues.length < 1)
    {
        return "-";
    }

    // filter verificationvalues based on current test id
    let filteredValues = verificationCriterion.VerificationValues.filter(x => x.TestID == this.testId);

    if (filteredValues.length < 1)
    {
        return "-";
    }

    this.noTarget = '';

    if (filteredValues[0].VerificationTargets.length < 1) {
        this.noTarget = 'rgb(211, 211, 211)';
    }

    // return smallest value if the are more values for one criteria (could be from multiple sequences);
    return filteredValues.reduce((x:any,y:any) => x.ValueDouble < y.ValueDouble ? x : y).ValueDouble;
  }
  
  calculateBackgroundColor(i: any, j: any)
  {
    let value = this.getValue(i,j);   

    switch(value)
    {
      case "-":
        return 'rgb(211, 211, 211)'; //gray
      case "*":
        return 'rgb(102, 153, 204)'; //blue

        default:
         return  this.noTarget === 'rgb(211, 211, 211)' ? 'rgb(211, 211, 211)' : this.textColor;
  }
}
}



@Component({
  selector: "verification-indicator-cell",
  templateUrl: "./verification.indicator.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./verification.indicator.component.scss"],
})
export class VerificationIndicator implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  data: any;

  @Output() 
  textColorChange = new EventEmitter<string>();
  
  
  textColor: string = "white";

  calculateIndicator(): void {
    
    //...some  code

    this.isRedCondition()
      ? (this.textColor = "red")
      : this.isGreenCondition()
      ? (this.textColor = "rgb(87, 165, 68)")
      : (this.textColor = "gold");

      this.textColorChange.emit(this.textColor);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.verificationTarget = this.data["VerificationTarget"];
    this.calculateIndicator();
  }

  ngOnChanges(): void {
    this.calculateIndicator();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [setter](https://www.typescripttutorial.net/typescript-tutorial/typescript-getters-setters/) in typescript.In your `VerificationGrid` component define a private property and then use a setter property and set the private property inside that something like

```
private _textColor:string='white';
@Input() set textColor(val:string){
  this._textColor=val;
};
```

Now your _textColor property will have the latest value

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't seem to change that behavior.

Comment: @Andrei do `console.log(val)` in the setter if you still don't fine the issue please create a stack blitz of your issue and share the link

Comment: I'm not aware that this does anything different than the OP case. Looks like something is breaking the change detection process. You can try `ngOnChanges` for troubleshooting